# Ansible Failed to set permissions on the temporary files

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I'd like to make a playbook that shows me the user currently in use.

this is my ansible cfg:

```
[defaults]
inventory=inventory
remote_user=adminek

[privilege_escalation]
become=true

[ssh_connection]
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
ssh_args = -o ControlMaster=no -o ControlPath=none -o ControlPersist=no
pipelining = false
```

and this is my playbook

```
---
- name: show currenty users 
  hosts: server_a
  
  tasks:
    - name: test user - root
      shell: "whoami"
      register: myvar_root

    - name: test user - user2
      become: true
      become_user: user2    
      shell: "whoami"
      register: myvar_user2


    - name: print myvar root
      debug:
        var: myvar_root.stdout_lines

    - name: print myvar user2
      debug:
        var: myvar_user2.stdout
```

taks "test user - root" work fine and give me output

```
ok: [172.22.0.134] => {
    "myvar_root.stdout_lines": [
        "root"
    ]
}
```

taks "test user - user2" give me output

```
fatal: [172.22.0.134]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Failed to set permissions on the temporary files Ansible needs to create when becoming an unprivileged user (rc: 1, err: chown: changing ownership `/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1621340458.2-11599-141854654478770/': Operation permited\nchown: changing ownership `/var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1621340458.2-11599-141854654478770/AnsiballZ_command.py': Operation permited\n}). For information on working around this, see https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user"}
```

Explanation:
adminek- sudoer user
User2 - non sudoers users

OS - Scientific Linux release 6.9

Additionaly I hgad similar problem on ubuntu 18.04 but when i installed acl begun works

Someone know what is wrong?
Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@F1ko thanks for reply.

I did what you wont and I installed acl on my host, but steal was wrong.
I added to visudo.

```
Defaults:user2 !requiretty
Defaults:adminek !requiretty
```

I dont know it's ok and secure but work.

Answer (score 3):

One of the following options should fix your issue:

- Ensure `sudo` is installed on the remote host
- Ensure `acl` is installed on the remote host
- Uncomment the following lines in `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`:

```
allow_world_readable_tmpfiles = True
pipelining = True
```

Comment: be careful with allow_world_readable_tmpfiles ->  "If any of the parameters passed to the module are sensitive in nature, and you do not trust the remote machines, then this is a potential security risk." source: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html#becoming-an-unprivileged-user

Answer (score -2):

for me it worked installing the acl package in host

```
- name: Install required packaged
      yum:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        - acl
        - python3-pip
```

in my case I used centos/07, if you use ubuntu, change yum to apt.